# Force virtual machine to only connect to the internet through a VPN whose IP dynamically changes, and never use ISP connection?

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, routing

I want to set up a Windows virtual machine where the only network access allowed is via a VPN connection. If the VPN connection fails, the VM should never be allowed access through my normal (ISP) connection. I've heard of software such as VPNLifeguard which checks periodically for the VPN being down, but this doesn't strike me as an elegant or secure solution.

I've read elsewhere that you can configure firewalls to block all traffic that's not going through your VPN's IP address, but what if your VPN IP is dynamic, or you can select multiple VPN servers to switch between? Then you'd have to change the firewall rules every time. Ditto for solutions which involve editing the routing tables.

Is there a solution which can take into account a VPN connection with a dynamic IP?

Since this is on a VM I can use either Windows XP or 7, and can get whatever firewall you recommend.

Comment: What virtualization solution are you using? That's why you're getting downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been helpful to know how you are hosting the VMs, what hypervisor are you using?

Either way I'll assume its Hyper-V simply because you are talking Windows here.  However, the same really will apply to VMware as well.

Remember a VM is a physical computer, its just hosted on top of another machine.  With that in mind, can you prevent a physical machine from accessing the internet but still allow it to use a VPN connection?  In some cases you can but its pretty difficult to setup and more of a pain to manage.

A VPN connection has to be carried over some sort of internet connection so your question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  You must have an established internet connection before your VPN tunnel can then establish itself.

So to answer your overall question, no you must provide internet access to the machine which would then have to initiate the VPN connection.  There is no way to abstract this function out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not quite sure why my question has received negative votes but I appreciate your help. I understand that in order to establish the VPN connection, my ISP connection must reach the machine. However, is there no way to force all the OS application traffic to *not* use the "raw" ISP connection and instead only connect through the VPN?

Comment: Depending on the VPN package on the client you may be able to force all traffic over the VPN but until the VPN connection is established they would have free roam.  Look for a flag such as `force the use of the remote gateway`.